# SQL says the code syntax by DECLARE isn´t correct

Tags: mysql, count, distinct, declare

I'm trying to get more data at once to export these data in an document.
So I wanted to use distinct to reduce the data and wanted then to get out the columnrows with these.

```
DECLARE @counter INT, 
        @loop INT, 
        @company_name VARCHAR(40)

SET     @counter = 10,
        @loop = 0 

WHILE @loop <= @counter

SELECT Company, Firstname, Surname, eMail, Adress, Place, Phone, Fax FROM `table` 
WHERE Company = PRINT @company_name 
        BEGIN SET @counter = (
                SELECT COUNT (SET @company_name = (
                    SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM `table`
                )) FROM `table`
           )
        SET @loop = @loop +1
       END
```

Comment: Is your code literally using `table` surrounded by ticks, or do you have a real table name in there?

Comment: This is an odd query, why are you looping in the first place?

Comment: Seems a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  Why not do a simple `select distinct`?

Comment: i have a real tablename there^^
im in beginner at coding but i think query must to be repeated again and again to get the data out that i need

Comment: i´m working with mySQL

Comment: maybe i should use a mySQL procedure to get the script in work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the loop instead of counter

```
SET @loop = @loop +1
```

instead of

```
SET @counter = @counter +1
```

Comment: Hi @Wollhaar if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: it´s right that i it´s better with that syntax, but it is not solve the problem i have